# Проблема с Docker, ошибка ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache, docker

Всем привет.

Делаю первые шаги в Docker и сразу столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть тестовый проект из двух файлов: index.php и собственно сам Dockerfile.

Содержимое index.php простое:

```
<?php print 'Hello World'; ?>
```

Содержимое Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 8088
```

Потом я собираю образ:

```
docker build -t test-php .
```

Пытаюсь запустить:

```
docker run -p 8088:8088 -d test-php
```

И тут по идее по адресу http://localhost:8088 я должен увидеть Hello World.

Но вместо этого я вижу:

```
Страница недоступна
Сайт localhost не отправил данных.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Я начал смотреть логи контейнера, и увидел следующее:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
... waiting apache2:
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Данную ошибку удалось исправить добавлением нескольких команд в Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN service apache2 restart
EXPOSE 8088
```

Ошибка пропала. Но все равно по адресу http://localhost:8088 я вижу ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему так?

Comment: может это связано с тем, что apache слушает по дефолту 80 порт?

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо.
Добавил строчку RUN echo "Listen 8088" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf в Dockerfile и все получилось.